# Change cell fill color when selected without changing original color when deselected

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel 2010 worksheet and the following requirements:

1. When a cell is selected, its fill color must change to indicate it's selected and revert to its original color when another cell is selected.  With the code below, the cell reverts to white, even though it may have been pink before being selected.
2. If the user saves the file, I do not want the color of the selected cell saved as part of the file (e.g with the code below, if I select a cell, save, close and reopen the file, that cell has that color even though it's not selected).
3. The code must work on a protected sheet
4. The code must work on merged cells

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Static xLastRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
xLastRng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
Set xLastRng = Target

End Sub
```

Comment: Opinion Piece: the more advanced you get in excel the more you realize code like this isn’t necessary. The cell already is outlined when you click it. Ask yourself what is the real value added by doing something like this? How will this impact users with or without?

Comment: for 1. save the color index in another static variable then use that when resetting it.   For 2. you will need to use an on close event.  so you may need to save the variables as global static instead so both events can reach them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting task! It will require a few steps:

1) Add a Standard Module (e.g. Module1) and create two Public Variables:

```
Public g_lngEXISTINGCOL        As Long
Public g_rngPREVIOUSTARGET     As Excel.Range
```

2) Going back to your Worksheet Event, you need to use the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngTarget               As Excel.Range

    On Error Resume Next
        Set rngTarget = Application.Intersect(Me.UsedRange, Target)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rngTarget Is Nothing Then
        If rngTarget.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            With Target
                If Not g_rngPREVIOUSTARGET Is Nothing Then
                    If g_lngEXISTINGCOL = 16777215 Then
                        g_rngPREVIOUSTARGET.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                    Else
                        g_rngPREVIOUSTARGET.Interior.Color = g_lngEXISTINGCOL
                    End If
                End If
                g_lngEXISTINGCOL = .Interior.Color
                Set g_rngPREVIOUSTARGET = Target
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

3) In order to return to your original Interior Color before saving your Workbook, you need to double-click on "ThisWorkbook" and add BeforeSave Event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not g_rngPREVIOUSTARGET Is Nothing Then
        g_rngPREVIOUSTARGET.Interior.Color = g_lngEXISTINGCOL
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: it works but i forgot to mention that the sheet will be protected. ive added requirement 3 to the question as it throws an error as it appears the vb code cannot change the cell color as its proteced. ideas welcome - i'm having a look now aswell myself on google

Comment: Hi, should be quite easy. Add the following two lines to both Worksheet and Workbook Events (I assume that your password is "test"):

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="test"
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="test"

This should be a part of your IF statement. So for Worksheet event, Unprotect should happen one line after "If Not rngTarget Is Nothing Then" and then Protect it before the last "End If" statement. The same goes for Workbook Event (insert it inside your If statement).

Comment: That works perfect -another option is : when protecting the work book you must can enable "allow users of this workbook to" "format cells" . I have a new requirement. sorry about this - ive added requirement 4 - some of the excel cells are merged and hence the code doesn't work for merged cells. Any quick fix for this ?

Comment: Oki doks - in your Worksheet event, try adjusting "If rngTarget.Cells.Count = 1 Then" to "If rngTarget.Cells.Count = 1 Or rngTarget.Cells.MergeCells Then"

Comment: it works. you are a genius. thank you very much for the help.